# Делаю запросы между двумя локальными серверами, возникает ошибка CORP

Tags: html, post, get, localhost

Работаю на WinCCOA, развернул на нем локальный сервер (localhost:86) и параллельно на том же ПК развернул другой локальный сервер (localhost:5000), пытаюсь передать GET запрос с одного локального сервера на другой, но из-за того что порты разные появляется ошибка CORP. Расскажите как можно обойти ошибку не прибегая к настройке сервера и браузера? Может нужно что-то передать в заголовке метода GET?
Пример запроса:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open("GET", "/methodSendToWincc?n=" + n, true);
x.send();
```

Comment: Во-первых, ошибка называется вовсе не CORP. Во-вторых, если вы почитаете в интернете, что это такое и почему существует, то и разберётесь, что с этим делать

Comment: Ну а "не прибегая к настройке сервера" - нельзя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для обхода ошибки CORS вы можете использовать прокси-сервер. Для этого необходимо создать свой сервер (например, на Node.js) и настроить его таким образом, чтобы он получал запросы с одного локального сервера (localhost:5000), а затем перенаправлял их на другой локальный сервер (localhost:86).

Например, если вы используете Express.js, то пример кода для создания такого сервера может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');

const app = express();

app.get('/methodSendToWincc', (req, res) => {
  const url = 'http://localhost:86/methodSendToWincc?n=' + req.query.n;
  req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('Proxy server is running on http://localhost:5000');
});
```

Затем вы можете изменить свой запрос на:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open("GET", "http://localhost:5000/methodSendToWincc?n=" + n, true);
x.send();
```

Таким образом, запрос будет отправлен на прокси-сервер, который передаст его на нужный локальный сервер без ошибки CORS.

Comment: В любом случае без взаимодействий с сервером вряд ли есть способ реализовать это, да и не стоит, больше головной боли будет

Comment: Спасибо большое, за информацию!